# Can you expect JSON schema compliant data from a RAML API or is it just for posting data?

Tags: json, rest, jsonschema, raml

I am talking to an API that uses RAML. I am both downloading and uploading data to it. 
When uploading data I had previously downloaded, I got a JSON Schema violation error, saying some of the parameters in the JSON objects were not allowed.

I realize the data i received is not following the JSON schema.

Is this kind of behavior a violation against the RAML principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What columns you GET and what columns you are allowed to POST may not be the same. For example, if you GET a user, it might include a `user_id` column, but you usually won't be allowed to write to it!

It's difficult to give a fuller answer without seeing the RAML spec document.
It's totally possible and valid to define different schemas for each HTTP method.

Comment: Thank you. I was not paying attention. The RAML actually specifies two different JSON Schemas, one general and one for uploading. This got me on the right track.